# Swapping/Cashing out?

Tags: blockchain

I want to start out by saying I know nothing about this kind of stuff. But, my husband and I have Ethereum in some wallet and has been trying to "cash out" (not sure if this term is correct) but this company he is working with states he cannot do that during this current update (dencun I believe?)

I am wondering, this is correct information? Can he currently NOT do anything with his Ethereum stocks?
Is this update happening currently? When I have been looking online it says it isn't happening until March 13.

Comment: Ether is a cryptocurrency that can be exchanged freely in public exchanges (depending on the jurisdiction, etc. etc.). 

It is possible that the ether is staked. But withdrawals were available since last year. They could staked in a smart contract.

Also it is possible they are trying to scam you.

You didn't provide any details, so we cannot say anything concrete about the situation.

Comment: Add platform details.